# How do I get DotNetOpenAuth to open a popup window for authentication?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, openid, popup, dotnetopenauth

I am relatively new to web development, so perhaps this is a rookie question.  I am trying to set up an ASP.NET MVC web site to implement DotNetOpenAuth as an OpenID relying party.

Right now it is all functioning, so that is pretty exciting.  My goal though was to have the OpenID authentication take place it a popup window.  This seems to be the default behavior when you using WebForms with the DNOA custom controls, but I haven't been able to figure it out in MVC.

I thought I was getting close with this:

```
var request = OpenIdRp.CreateRequest(id);
request.AddExtension(new UIRequest(Mode = UIModes.Popup));
```

But the Mode field of the UIRequest is read-only.

Does anybody know how to create a request that tells the OpenID provider to open a popup window?

Thanks for any help.  So far I have been unable to track down any samples of this in action.

Answer (score 2):

On the v.3.4.5 I am using, Mode property of the UIRequest has both getter and setter.

```
var req = openid.CreateRequest(openid_identifier);                      

                    // Add UI Request 
                    if (req.DiscoveryResult.IsExtensionSupported<UIRequest>())
                    {
                        req.AddExtension(new UIRequest()
                        {
                            Mode = UIModes.Popup
                        });
```

You have to create the popup yourself. After the authentication takes place, you should refresh the parent window and close the popup.
At the form's submission I have

```
<form action="/Account/OpenIdLogOn" target="popupWin" onsubmit="return openWindow('/Account/OpenIdLogOn', 'popupWin', 500, 500);">
```

where

```
function openWindow(url, wname, width, height) {
    window.open(url, wname, "height=" + height + ",width=" + width + "location = 0, status = 1, resizable = 0, scrollbars=1, toolbar = 0");
    return true;
}
```

and at the result view I have the following javascript

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            if (window.opener) {
                window.opener.location.href = window.opener.location.href;
                window.close();
            }
        });
    </script>
```

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

The Nerddinner site has exactly what you need. It's written in MVC, and you can download the source code here: http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/ .

Comment: Hey Gazza,  Thanks for pointing that out.  Unfortunately it seems to me (I could be wrong) that NerdDinner still implements OpenID by using the custom controls provided by DNOA.  I was hoping to implement my own solution in code.  I read that there is a design standard for OpenID providers that tells the provider to perform authentication in a pop up window, rather than the same window.  Perhaps I am misreading it, because I haven't been able to find a way to invoke it.  The article I'm referencing is http://wiki.openid.net/Details-of-UX-Best-Practices-for-OPs#UXFlow under UX Flow.